# How to clean these white stains from my grout?

Tags: cleaning

I've tried a lot of products, non seems to work, these are the pictures of what I see:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GEtx.jpg

The normal color is grey, however some white stains appeared in some of them, they seem to be very hard, like mineral deposits of sorts.

Any ideas what product I could use to remove them?.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried CLR (Calcium, Lime & Rust) remover it may do the trick. Once cleaned I would seal the grout to prevent this from happening again.

Comment: No, will look into it.

Comment: I didn't find that particular one, but went to a store and bought phosphoric acid. It didn't do shit. I will search for that CLR thingy.

Comment: Here is a link [to CLR](https://www.walmart.com/ip/14574716?wmlspartner=wlpa&selectedSellerId=0&adid=22222222228009734578&wl0=&wl1=g&wl2=m&wl3=40343265392&wl4=aud-261800282140:pla-78303464552&wl5=9033051&wl6=&wl7=&wl8=&wl9=pla&wl10=8175035&wl11=online&wl12=14574716&wl13=&veh=sem). I have found it at regular grocery and big box stores in the past. I have never looked at the ingredients that I remember but the it has worked well for me.

Comment: Yeah the problem is I live in Denmark :P.